# Kusto: Summarize different rows having real number values in a column in fixed bins of fixed sizes

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have 3 tables like this: -

```
Table A:
------
Delay 
------
2.3
4.5
6.7
12.36

Table B:
-------
Delay 
-------
12.31
74.556
16.744

Table C:
-------
Delay 
-------
2.35
8.5
637.3
5.36
1.23
```

I want to join them and have delay in bins of sizes(<0.5, >0.5 and <1, >1 and <1.5, >1.5 and <2, >2), only these fixed sizes, nothing more.
I want the table like this: -

```
Delay | Source | Count 
-----------------------
<0.5  |  A     | 6
<0.5  |  B     | 16
<0.5  |  C     | 26
0.5-1 |  A     | 25
0.5-1 |  B     | 25
0.5-1 |  C     | 25
1-1.5 |  A     | 6
1-1.5 |  B     | 6
1-1.5 |  C     | 6
1.5-2 |  A     | 2
1.5-2 |  B     | 2
1.5-2 |  C     | 2
>2    |  A     | 36
>2    |  B     | 36
>2    |  C     | 36
```

What is the most effective query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
union withsource=Source TableA, TableB, TableC
| extend Delay = case(
    d < 0.5,            "A <0.5",
    d >= 0.5 and d < 1, "B 0.5-1",
    d >= 0.5 and d < 1, "C 0.5-1",
    d >= 1 and d < 1.5, "D 1-1.5",
    d >= 1.5 and d < 2, "E 1.5-2",
                        "F >2")
| summarize Count = count() by Source, Delay
| project-reorder Delay, Source, Count
| order by Delay asc, Source asc
| extend Delay = substring(Delay, 2)
```

The "tricks" needed to achieve what you want are:

- Use `union withsource=Source` - this will union your three tables and a new column named `Source` will contain the name of the original table
- `case` will do the division into buckets (note that I added a letter to all the options, in order to sort the buckets easily) - I then remove this letter at the last line of the query
- `project-reorder` to display the output column in the order you requested
- `order by` to sort the records to fit your needs (it's for this line that I added the A-F letters in the `case` - this ensures sorting according to what you asked)